# Morphia: retrieve MongoDb document as java object

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I can insert easily a java object into MongoDb database by using Morphia. Now, I want to retrieve the document and mapped it as java object. The MongoDB document is like this:

```
{
    "Name":"XXX",
    "Fingertemplate":{ "immutable" : { "size" : { "x" : 388 , "y" : 374} , "minutiae" : [ ........
```

My sample code is shown below:

```
@Entity(value="fingertable", noClassnameStored=true)
public class RecordFingerTemplate {
    @Id private ObjectId id;
    @Property private String name;
    @Embedded private FingerprintTemplate fingertemp;
    public RecordFingerTemplate (){

    }
    public RecordFingerTemplate(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId( final ObjectId id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public FingerprintTemplate getTemplate(){
        return fingertemp;
    }
    public void setTemplate(FingerprintTemplate template){
        this.fingertemp=fingertemp;
    }
}
```

and to save the object into the database I'm using `datastore.save(Object)` , it works perfectly
Now I want to retrieve the document and getting the fingerprint template object.

```
List<RecordFingerTemplate> result=datastore.createQuery(RecordFingerTemplate.class)
                .field("name").containsIgnoreCase("john")
                .order("name")
                .asList();
```

> Error: ** org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException:Error setting
>   value from converter (PassthroughConverter) for ImmutableTemplate.size
>   to {"x": 388, "y.........**

Answer (score 0):

Try moving/adding the `@Embedded` annotation to `FingerprintTemplate` and explicitly calling `map()` on your types.  The lazy mapping has some gaps in it and I'm afraid you might be slipping through such a case.